Why is tkinter.OptionMenu['menu'] = None?
When I close my acquisition_para(), and try to reopen it (like every other parameter) it gives me this error:
menu.delete(0, 'end')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'

I don't understand why because it works for the first time, my menu is :
menu = self.menu['menu'] and self.menu = tk.OptionMenu()

thus, I don't understand why menu = None type
I try to do a GUI, thus I have the options clickable by a Tkinter Button to show the frame of the option parameters.
Here is my code :
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing
from configparser import ConfigParser
import os
import hubconf
from datetime import datetime
import time


class Acquisition:
    #classe permettant d'avoir l'acquisition des caméras soit en auto soit via le paramétrage utilisateur
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, parent, frame, choices, voie):
        self.config = ConfigParser()
        self.voie = voie
        self.config.read("default_settings.ini")
        try:
            self.checkVar = tk.IntVar(value=self.config.getint("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{voie}"))
        except:
            self.create_default_settings()
        self.cropVar = tk.IntVar(value=self.config.getint("ACQUISITION",f"cropVar{voie}"))
        self.var = tk.StringVar(parent, self.config.get("ACQUISITION",f"current_camera{voie}"))
        self.checkVar = tk.IntVar(value=self.config.getint("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{voie}"))
        self.width = 1920
        self.height = 1080
        self.cam_settings = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video{voie-1} ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,framerate=25/1,width=1920,height=1080,colorimetry=bt709 ! nvvidconv  ! appsink "
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam_settings, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
        
        self.checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame, 
            text=f"Voie {voie}", 
            variable=self.checkVar,
            onvalue=1, 
            offvalue=0, 
            height=2,
            width=20,
            command=self.changeState
        )
        
        self.Crop_checkBox = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame, 
            text="Crop", 
            variable=self.cropVar,
            onvalue=1, 
            offvalue=0, 
            height=2,
            width=20,
        )

        self.menu_choices = choices
        self.menu = tk.OptionMenu(frame, self.var, *self.get_filtered_choices())
        self.root = frame
        self.save_settings_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Save", command=self.save_settings)
        self.checkbox.grid(row=voie)
        self.menu.grid(row=voie, column=1)
        self.Crop_checkBox.grid(row=voie, column=2)
        self.save_settings_button.grid(row=voie, column=4)
        self.changeState()

        self.var.trace('w', self.update_options)
        Acquisition.instances.append(self)
        
        self.refresh_all_menus()  # Ensure menus are updated after initialization

    def create_default_settings(self):
        #Permet de créer les paramètres par défauts dans le fichier defaults_settings.ini
        self.config.read("default_settings.ini")
        create_section(self.config)
            
        self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{self.voie}","0")
        self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"cropVar{self.voie}","0")
        self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"current_camera{self.voie}","Choose your camera")
        with open('default_settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            self.config.write(configfile)

    def save_settings(self):
        #Permet de sauvegarder les paramètres utilisateur dans le fichier defaults_settings.ini
        self.config.read("default_settings.ini")
        self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{self.voie}",f"{self.checkVar.get()}")
        self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"cropVar{self.voie}",f"{self.cropVar.get()}")
        self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"current_camera{self.voie}",f"{self.var.get()}")
        with open('default_settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            self.config.write(configfile)   

    def update_options(self, *args):
        self.height = int(self.camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        self.width = int(self.camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        self.refresh_all_menus()

    def refresh_all_menus(self):
        for instance in Acquisition.instances:
            instance.refresh_menu()

    def refresh_menu(self):
        #permet de refresh les deux menus de choix de caméra pour avoir la caméra souhaitée
        menu = self.menu['menu']
        menu.delete(0, 'end')
        filtered_choices = self.get_filtered_choices()
        for option in filtered_choices:
            menu.add_command(label=option, command=lambda value=option: self.var.set(value))

    def get_filtered_choices(self):
        #permet de filtrer les choix de caméra possible et enlever celui déjà utilisé
        selected_choices = {instance.var.get() for instance in Acquisition.instances if instance.var.get() != 'choose your camera'}
        return [choice for choice in self.menu_choices if choice not in selected_choices]

    def changeState(self):
        #si une voix n'est pas cochée alors rien n'est sélectionnable en terme de paramètre la concernant
        if self.checkVar.get() == 1:
            self.menu.configure(state='normal')
            self.Crop_checkBox.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.menu.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Crop_checkBox.configure(state='disabled')

and for the calling
global encart_voie1, encart_voie2
def acquisition_para(root): ###
    frame = tk.Toplevel()
    handler = lambda : onCloseOtherFrame(root, frame)
    

    choices = ['none', 'CS HD', 'CS LP', 'CS VIS']

    encart_voie1 = menu.Acquisition(root, frame, choices, 1)
    encart_voie2 = menu.Acquisition(root, frame, choices, 2)

    tk.Button(frame, text="Close", command=handler).grid(row=4,column=2, sticky="E")    
    frame.mainloop()
    return encart_voie1, encart_voie2


def hide(root):
    root.withdraw()

def onCloseOtherFrame(root,frame):
    frame.destroy()
    show(root)

def show(root):
    root.update()

def main():##
    root = tk.Tk()
    affichage = menu.Affichage(root)
    demo = menu.Demonstration(root)
    record = menu.Enregistrement(root)
    #démarrer l'interface principale
    #rien fonctionne, implémenter ça : https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/26/tkinter-how-to-show-hide-a-window/

    tk.Button(root, text="►",command=exec_all).grid()
    tk.Button(root, text="■",command=end_all).grid(row=0,column=1)
    #tk.Button(root, text=f"{date}",command=date_config).grid(column=2)
    tk.Button(root, text="Paraètres ACQUISITION",command=lambda:acquisition_para(root)).grid(row=0,column=3)
    tk.Button(root, text="Paramètres AFFICHAGE",command=affichage.params).grid(row=0,column=4)
    tk.Button(root, text="Paramètres ENREGISTREMENT",command=record.params).grid(row=0,column=5)
    tk.Button(root, text="Paramètres DEMONSTRATION",command=demo.params).grid(row=0,column=6)
    tk.Button(root, text="SYNTHESE",command=exe_conclude).grid(row=0,column=7)
    root.mainloop()```


Thank you man, i've done something myself and it works, here is the code if you want:
class Acquisition:
#classe permettant d'avoir l'acquisition des caméras soit en auto soit via le paramétrage utilisateur
instances = []

def __init__(self, root, choices, voie):
    self.config = ConfigParser()
    self.voie = voie
    self.config.read("default_settings.ini")
    self.choices = choices
    try:
        self.checkVar = tk.IntVar(value=self.config.getint("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{voie}"))
    except:
        self.create_default_settings()
    self.cropVar = tk.IntVar(value=self.config.getint("ACQUISITION",f"cropVar{voie}"))
    
    self.checkVar = tk.IntVar(value=self.config.getint("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{voie}"))
    self.width = 1920
    self.height = 1080
    self.cam_settings = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video{voie-1} ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,framerate=25/1,width=1920,height=1080,colorimetry=bt709 ! nvvidconv  ! appsink "
    self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam_settings, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
    self.var = tk.StringVar(root, self.config.get("ACQUISITION",f"current_camera{self.voie}"))
    self.var.trace('w', self.update_options)
    
    Acquisition.instances.append(self)
    
def params(self):
    frame = tk.Toplevel()

    for instance in Acquisition.instances:
        
        instance.checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame, 
            text=f"Voie {instance.voie}", 
            variable=instance.checkVar,
            onvalue=1, 
            offvalue=0, 
            height=2,
            width=20,
            command=instance.changeState
        )
        
        instance.Crop_checkBox = tk.Checkbutton(
            frame, 
            text="Crop", 
            variable=instance.cropVar,
            onvalue=1, 
            offvalue=0, 
            height=2,
            width=20,
        )

        instance.menu_choices = instance.choices
        instance.menu = tk.OptionMenu(frame, instance.var, *instance.get_filtered_choices())
        instance.save_settings_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Save", command=instance.save_settings)
        instance.checkbox.grid(row=instance.voie)
        instance.menu.grid(row=instance.voie, column=1)
        instance.Crop_checkBox.grid(row=instance.voie, column=2)
        instance.save_settings_button.grid(row=instance.voie, column=4)
        instance.changeState()


        
    self.refresh_all_menus()  # Ensure menus are updated after initialization
    tk.Button(frame, text="Close", command=frame.destroy).grid(row=4,column=4, sticky="E")
    frame.mainloop()

def create_default_settings(self):
    #Permet de créer les paramètres par défauts dans le fichier defaults_settings.ini
    self.config.read("default_settings.ini")
    create_section(self.config)
        
    self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{self.voie}","0")
    self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"cropVar{self.voie}","0")
    self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"current_camera{self.voie}","Choose your camera")
    with open('default_settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        self.config.write(configfile)

def save_settings(self):
    #Permet de sauvegarder les paramètres utilisateur dans le fichier defaults_settings.ini
    self.config.read("default_settings.ini")
    self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"checkVar{self.voie}",f"{self.checkVar.get()}")
    self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"cropVar{self.voie}",f"{self.cropVar.get()}")
    self.config.set("ACQUISITION",f"current_camera{self.voie}",f"{self.var.get()}")
    with open('default_settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        self.config.write(configfile)   

def update_options(self, *args):
    self.height = int(self.camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    self.width = int(self.camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    self.refresh_all_menus()

def refresh_all_menus(self):
    for instance in Acquisition.instances:
        instance.refresh_menu()

def refresh_menu(self):
    #permet de refresh les deux menus de choix de caméra pour avoir la caméra souhaitée
    menu = self.menu['menu']
    menu.delete(0, 'end')
    filtered_choices = self.get_filtered_choices()
    for option in filtered_choices:
        menu.add_command(label=option, command=lambda value=option: self.var.set(value))

def get_filtered_choices(self):
    #permet de filtrer les choix de caméra possible et enlever celui déjà utilisé
    selected_choices = {instance.var.get() for instance in Acquisition.instances if instance.var.get() != 'choose your camera'}
    return [choice for choice in self.menu_choices if choice not in selected_choices]

def changeState(self):
    #si une voix n'est pas cochée alors rien n'est sélectionnable en terme de paramètre la concernant
    if self.checkVar.get() == 1:
        self.menu.configure(state='normal')
        self.Crop_checkBox.configure(state='normal')
    else:
        self.menu.configure(state='disabled')
        self.Crop_checkBox.configure(state='disabled')

and for the call:
def acquisition_para(encart_voie1,encart_voie2): ###
encart_voie1.params()
encart_voie2.params()



def main():##
choices = ['none', 'CS HD', 'CS LP', 'CS VIS']
root = tk.Tk()
affichage = menu.Affichage(root)
demo = menu.Demonstration(root)
record = menu.Enregistrement(root)
encart_voie1 = menu.Acquisition(root,choices, 1)
encart_voie2 = menu.Acquisition(root,choices, 2)
#démarrer l'interface principale
#rien fonctionne, implémenter ça : https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/26/tkinter-how-to-show-hide-a-window/

tk.Button(root, text="►",command=exec_all).grid()
tk.Button(root, text="■",command=end_all).grid(row=0,column=1)
#tk.Button(root, text=f"{date}",command=date_config).grid(column=2)
tk.Button(root, text="Paraètres ACQUISITION",command=lambda:acquisition_para(encart_voie1,encart_voie2)).grid(row=0,column=3)
tk.Button(root, text="Paramètres AFFICHAGE",command=affichage.params).grid(row=0,column=4)
tk.Button(root, text="Paramètres ENREGISTREMENT",command=record.params).grid(row=0,column=5)
tk.Button(root, text="Paramètres DEMONSTRATION",command=demo.params).grid(row=0,column=6)
tk.Button(root, text="SYNTHESE",command=lambda:exe_conclude(affichage,demo,record)).grid(row=0,column=7)
root.mainloop()


When you close the window created inside acquisition_para(), the class list Acquisition.instances will has instances of Acquisition that containing destroyed widgets of the closed window.
So when open the window second time and call refresh_all_menus() which in turn calls refresh_menu(), then self.menu["menu"] will return None for destroyed OptionMenu instance.
You need to remove those instances in the class list related to the closed window after closing the window:
def acquisition_para(root): ###
    frame = tk.Toplevel()
    handler = lambda : onCloseOtherFrame(root, frame)

    choices = ['none', 'CS HD', 'CS LP', 'CS VIS']

    encart_voie1 = menu.Acquisition(root, frame, choices, 1)
    encart_voie2 = menu.Acquisition(root, frame, choices, 2)

    tk.Button(frame, text="Close", command=handler).grid(row=4,column=2, sticky="E")
    # don't call mainloop() more than once
    #frame.mainloop()
    # instead call wait_window()
    frame.grab_set()
    frame.wait_window()
    # remove instances of Acquisition related to this window
    menu.Acquisition.instances.remove(encart_voie1)
    menu.Acquisition.instances.remove(encart_voie2)
    # below return statement is useless
    return encart_voie1, encart_voie2

